# uwp incremental loadingkeep calling GetPagedItemAsync infinitely

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I have a uwp app and I am using **Windows Community Toolkit** for the **Incremental Loading** feature on my list.

Sample repo to reproduce issue: https://github.com/touseefbsb/IncrementalLoadingBug

**How to reproduce the issue**

1. Close the provided project and open it in visual studio
2. Run the app.
3. On top left side you will see 2 gridview items, click 1st of them called "Evidences"
4. Notice that below in the Listview, Evidence items will keep on adding in a loop because **GetPagedItemAsync** is being called repeatedly without any scrolling.

**Explanation**

So on my homepage I have a GridView on top bound to a collection of **ModuleConfigurationDto** and upon its item being selection I want to show the **List of Evidences** below the GridView, as each item has its own list of evidences and the selected item should show its list below.

So I used the community toolkit for incremental loading purpose that upon an item being selected it should load first set of items and then only on scrolling it calls the other set of items and so on.

Now the problem I am having it that it keeps calling **GetPagedItemsAsync** repeatedly even if I return a list with a single item in this method, and if I return an empty list in this method then it doesn't have this issue and UI just remains empty that way.

### Code

**MainPage**

```
 <Grid x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridView
        x:Name="TopListView"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.AppVM.EvidencesConfigurationList}"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.AppVM.TopListViewItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ModulesConfigurationDto">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind QueryCount}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="{x:Bind DisplayName}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

    <ListView
        x:Name="AllEvidencesListView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Header="{x:Bind ViewModel.AppVM.TopListViewItem.DisplayName}"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.AppVM.TopListViewItem.Evidences}" />
</Grid>
```

**ModuleConfigurationDto**

```
 public class ModulesConfigurationDto : Observable
{
    private int _queryCount;

    public string ModuleCode { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }


    public int QueryCount { get => _queryCount; set => Set(ref _queryCount, value); }

    #region JsonIgnore

    [JsonIgnore]
    public object Evidences { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

**AppViewModel**

```
 public class AppViewModel : Observable
{
    private ModulesConfigurationDto _topListViewItem;
    private ObservableCollection<ModulesConfigurationDto> _evidencesConfigurationList;

    public ModulesConfigurationDto TopListViewItem { get => _topListViewItem; set => Set(ref _topListViewItem, value); }

    public ObservableCollection<ModulesConfigurationDto> EvidencesConfigurationList { get { if (_evidencesConfigurationList is null) { _evidencesConfigurationList = new ObservableCollection<ModulesConfigurationDto>(); } return _evidencesConfigurationList; } set => Set(ref _evidencesConfigurationList, value); }


    public async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);//fake web api call

        List<ModulesConfigurationDto> result = new List<ModulesConfigurationDto> {
            new ModulesConfigurationDto { DisplayName = "RecentEvidences", ModuleCode = "TM", QueryCount = 27 },
            new ModulesConfigurationDto { DisplayName = "Evidences", ModuleCode = "TM", QueryCount = 27 }};

        if (result?.Count > 0)
        {
            EvidencesConfigurationList.Clear();

            IEnumerable<ModulesConfigurationDto> evidencesConfigurationList = result.Where(a => a.ModuleCode == "TM");

            foreach (ModulesConfigurationDto item in evidencesConfigurationList)
            {
                item.Evidences = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<EvidencesSource, EvidenceDTO>();
            }
            EvidencesConfigurationList.AddRange(evidencesConfigurationList);
        }
    }
}
```

**Evidence Source (for incremental loading)**

```
 public class EvidencesSource : IIncrementalSource<EvidenceDTO>
{
    public AppViewModel AppVM => App.AppVM;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<EvidenceDTO>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var evidences = new List<EvidenceDTO>();
        await Task.Delay(500); // fake web api call
        evidences.Add(new EvidenceDTO ());
        return evidences;
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

as per answer of "Faywang - MSFT" I tried the following.

```
private readonly List<EvidenceDTO> evidences;

    public EvidencesSource()
    {
        evidences = new List<EvidenceDTO>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            evidences.Add(new EvidenceDTO());
        }
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<EvidenceDTO>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {            
        await Task.Delay(500); // fake web api call
        var result = (from dto in evidences
                      select dto).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        return result;
    }
```

but it didn't solve the issue, as the default pageSize value is 20, so GetPagesItemsAsync runs 1st time to get first 20 items and then again calls itself to get remaining 20, and then calls itself again a third time but this time because result returns empty so it doesn't call forth time and I look at the UI, there all 40 items already loaded, so somehow the method keeps calling itself until an empty result is returned.

**Update 2**

Now I tried the exact example from the **Windows Community Toolkit Sample App** and put a **PeopleListView** on the lower half of the page, and it is also showing same bug. I have updated the sample app with that code as well, you can see on the bottom half of the page, all 40 people are loaded in two times executing of the method without me scrolling it, and when I scroll it it already has all the items so this time it returns 0 items.

**Update 3**

If I increase the number of Evidences or people to 200, then for the 1st time it runs the the **GetPagedItemAsync** two times hence getting 40 items and then it stops executing it unless I scroll, so it works as expected only concern is why does it gets me two pages the first time when it should get me only one? This is an issue for me because I am getting the data from a webapi so can't make too many useless calls.

**Update 4**

If I change **pageSize** to **2** :

```
var collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<PeopleSource, Person>(itemsPerPage:2);
```

then it seems the method will keep calling itself until it has loaded about **40** items, which is about the double size of what the UI can show i.e : around 18, but interestingly if I  change the pageSize to **40**

```
 var collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<PeopleSource, Person>(itemsPerPage:40);
```

then then method calls itself 2 times hence loading around 80 items.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different implementation that might work for your needs: https://github.com/LanceMcCarthy/UwpProjects#incrementalloadingcollection

Here's the source in case that link breaks in the future:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace UwpHelpers.Controls.Common
{
    public class IncrementalLoadingCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
    {
        private readonly Func<CancellationToken, uint, Task<ObservableCollection<T>>> func;
        private uint maxItems;
        private bool isInfinite;
        private CancellationToken token;

        /// <summary>
        /// Infinite, incremental scrolling list supported by ListView and GridView
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="func"></param>
        public IncrementalLoadingCollection(Func<CancellationToken, uint, Task<ObservableCollection<T>>> func)
            : this(func, 0)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Incremental scrolling list supported by ListView and GridView
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="func">Task that retrieves the items</param>
        /// <param name="maxItems">Set to the maximum number of items to expect</param>
        public IncrementalLoadingCollection(Func<CancellationToken, uint, Task<ObservableCollection<T>>> func, uint maxItems)
        {
            this.func = func;
            if (maxItems == 0) //Infinite
            {
                isInfinite = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.maxItems = maxItems;
                isInfinite = false;
            }
        }

        public bool HasMoreItems
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return false;

                if (isInfinite)
                    return true;

                return this.Count < maxItems;
            }
        }

        public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(tkn => InternalLoadMoreItemsAsync(tkn, count));
        }

        private async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> InternalLoadMoreItemsAsync(CancellationToken passedToken, uint count)
        {
            ObservableCollection<T> tempList = null;
            this.token = passedToken;
            var baseIndex = this.Count;
            uint numberOfItemsToGet = 0;

            if (!isInfinite)
            {
                if (baseIndex + count < maxItems)
                {
                    numberOfItemsToGet = count;
                }
                else
                {
                    numberOfItemsToGet = maxItems - (uint) (baseIndex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                numberOfItemsToGet = count;
            }

            tempList = await func(passedToken, numberOfItemsToGet);

            if (tempList.Count == 0) //no more items, stop the incremental loading 
            {
                maxItems = (uint) this.Count;
                isInfinite = false;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in tempList)
                {
                    this.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return new LoadMoreItemsResult { Count = (uint) tempList.Count };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **Evidence Source.cs**,you can add the query statement below to get items from the collection according to pageIndex and pageSize parameters.In this case,it won't keep calling GetPagedItemsAsync repeatedly.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EvidenceDTO>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var evidences = new List<EvidenceDTO>();
    evidences.Add(new EvidenceDTO());
    var result = (from dto in evidences
                          select dto).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    await Task.Delay(500);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: that is strange do you mean I have to choose those 2 variables even if my paging logic doesn't require those 2 ?

Comment: Please see update 1 part of my question, Ive tried your solution in the sample repo app but it didn't work. @faywang-msft

Comment: I also reproduced the issue you showed in your update.I think it is by design.I saw you have reported this issue in [github](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2992).You can pay attention to it and see if anyone comes to reply.

Comment: yes I have even posted a 4th update in my question as I am noticing some design pattrens, and yes I am also keeping an eye on GitHub for this, this seems to be a strange design decision maybe, thankyou for the help :)

Comment: No bother.Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: Have you guys find any workaround, I'm stuck with similar issue. Initially it only loads 30 items, when i navigate  to another page and come back, it loads the full items in the database.